# SELECT records base on previous records contents (no relationship)

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a table, Events, that has an EventId (PK), Date, EmployeeId (FK), and StatusId (FK).

I need to select a record based on criteria of the record that happened directly before it (chronologically by date) for a particular employee. I have no idea how to do this since there isn't a relationship.

I'd like to select a count of all Events, grouped by EmployeeId, where:

(a) StatusId = 1
(b) The last event by that EmployeeId (chronologically) has a StatusId of 9.

Note that the preceding record for any event is not necessarily related to that employee.

*edited to note that I am using SQL Server, and that I am referencing the previous event chronologically by date!

Comment: *chronologically* based on Date or EventID

Comment: Why don't you store `parent_id` with reference to the previous row then? Btw, the answer strongly depends on what DBMS do you use. In Oracle, for example, thanks to analytic functions - it can be done very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Well, you can do a sub query i.e.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(*)
       FROM Events e1
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 StatusID FROM Events e2 WHERE e1.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID ORDER
       BY Date desc) = 9
GROUP BY EmployeeID, COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Events (EventId, Date, EmployeeId, StatusId)

select EmployeeId, count(*) from Events as e1
where e1.StatusId = 1
      and exists (select e2.EventID from Events as e2 
                 where e2.EmployeeId=e1.EmployeeId and e1.date > e2.date and e2.StatusId = 9 order by e2.date desc limit 1)
group by EmployeeId
```

something like that

Comment: This will not work if the previous record had a status other than 9.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear, but that is the intended functionality. Essentially, the business rules of the application require that an Event of StatusId = 9 MUST immediately precede an Event with StatusId = 1 to be counted as a "Successful" event. I then need to return a count of all "successful" events grouped by employee.